# Singly Linked List- Remove node with value "k", with O(1) space complexity

Tags: python, c, recursion, linked-list

So this was a problem on CodeSignal, and due to the space complexity constraint, a recursive algorithm must be used. The following C code passes all the tests, but i'm unable to figure out what's happening in the nested else if block. Here's the code.

```
//
// Definition for singly-linked list:
// typedef struct list_##name {
//   type value;
//   struct list_##name *next;
// } list_##name;
//
// list_##name *alloc_list_##name(type v) {
//   list_##name *l = calloc(1, sizeof(list_##name));
//   l->value = v;
//   return l;
// }
//
list_integer * solution(list_integer * l, int k) {
    
    if(l != NULL){ 
        if(l->value == k){
            return solution(l->next, k);
        } else {
            l->next = solution(l->next, k);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

And this is the same function in python

```
# Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
# class ListNode(object):
#   def __init__(self, x):
#     self.value = x
#     self.next = None
#
def solution(l, k):
    if l:
        if l.value == k:
            return solution(l.next, k)
        else:
            l.next = solution(l.next, k)
    return l
```

Can anyone please explain how the recursion part works? Thank you.

Comment: *"due to the space complexity constraint, a recursive algorithm must be used"*: that must be a misunderstanding. You speak of O(1) space complexity, but this solution does not have it. On the contrary, to get good space complexity, you should *not* use recursion.

Comment: @trincot, I believe they were referring to not using another variable (such a start or temp variable), but I am not so sure about it. Am I supposed to use a while loop? if so, how do I achieve the result without declaring another variable to keep track of the starting node.

Comment: *"Am I supposed to use a while loop?"*: that depends what your goal is. If your goal is O(1) space complexity, then: yes. Declaring a variable does not (always) mean you get a bad space complexity. You can use 20 variables and get O(1) space complexity. On the other hand, you can use no additional variable declaration (apart from the parameters), but recursion, and get O(n) space complexity, which is your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mutation migraine**

Because you are reassigning `l.next = ...`, it's surprisingly difficult to illustrate and talk about the computational process. But let's give it a try -

If I have `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> None` and I want to remove `3` -

The first node contains `value = 1` and `next = 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> none`. `1` does not match `k`, so

```py
l.next = solution(l.next, k)
```

Now we are solving for `2 -> 3 -> 4 -> None` and that will be set to `l.next`.

`value = 2` and `next = 3 -> 4 -> None`. `2` does not match `k`, so

```py
l.next = solution(l.next, k)
```

Now we are solving for `3 -> 4 -> None` and that will be set to `l.next`.

`value = 3` and `next = 4 -> None`. `3` **does** match `k`, so

```py
return l.next
```

So the `2` node, `next` is set to `4 -> None`, which becomes `2 -> 4 -> Nnoe`

And for the `1` node, `next` is set to the `2` node, so `1 -> 2 -> 4 -> None`

The `3` is removed!

**history lesson**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignment, and other side effects. Rather than modifying the list in place, A functional solution would create a *new* list. When a pure function is used, any function call be be substituted for its value without changing the meaning of the program -

```py
def remove(l, k):
  if not l:
    return l
  elif l.value == k:
    return l.next
  else:
    return ListNode(l.value, remove(l.next, k))
```

Because no mutations are being used, the process is extremely easy to communicate now -

```py
mylist = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3, ListNode(4, None))))
newList = remove(myList, 3)
newList = remove(ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3, ListNode(4, None)))), 3)
newList = ListNode(1, remove(ListNode(2, ListNode(3, ListNode(4, None))), 3))
newList = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, remove(ListNode(3, ListNode(4, None)), 3)))
newList = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(4, None)))
```

Comment: thank you for reaching out, my understanding of the problem is much better now.

Comment: Where did you see `return l.next`? That's not in the given code. The given code continues recursively, removing *all* nodes with the given value. And the history lesson code just removes *one*, so that's also not equivalent.